# Trying to attach a database to a currently open database but i'm getting an error saying ATTACH is not allowed from SQL

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air

I'm trying to attach a database(db2.sqlite) to a currently open database(db1.sqlite) and copy the contents of one of the tables in db2 into one of the tables in db1. The logical way to do this I thought was to use the attach command and then select all from db2 and insert into db1:-

attach 'C:\db2.sqlite' as newData;
insert into main.table1 select * from newData.table1

Both database's have identical table names (table1) and the exact same schema. To make sure my syntax was correct I tried this out in the Firefox SQLite Manager and everything worked perfectly.

Unfortunately when I tried the same method in my air application I got the following error:-
"ATTACH is not allowed from SQL.', operation:'execute', detailID:'2053'"

Can anyone please tell me why this isn't working?

Many Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 5):

From  the [Adobe LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/localDatabaseSQLSupport.html#unsupportedSQL):

> The following SQL elements and SQLite
>   features are supported in some SQLite
>   implementations, but are not supported
>   in Adobe AIR. Most of this
>   functionality is available through
>   methods of the SQLConnection class:
>
> ```
> * ATTACH: This functionality is available through the 
>   SQLConnection.attach() method.
> ```